# CentOS replace config error

Tags: centos, configuration, replace

I'm currently working on updating our CentOS server, however whenever I'm trying to use yum I get this error.

```
Config Error: Plugin "replace" requires API 2.6. Supported API is 2.5.
```

I'm new to CentOS and have previously only worked with Debian/Ubuntu servers and I can't seem to get rid of this error; Google also doesn't help much, hence I'm using this as a last resort before bothering my server company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use command `yum replace something-soft-name`, you can remove package yum-plugin-replace: `rpm -e yum-plugin-replace`

Comment: I'm a new user; it told me I couldn't yet. Have to post a bit more until I've reached the 15 level :(.

Comment: @NextGDev: If you link your Unix.SE account to your Stack Overflow account, you get 100 points. There may be additional points for completely filling out your user profile. (It's been years for me, so I don't rightly remember.)

Comment: This work only if Stack Overflow account has +200 reputation. But still, NextGDev can accept my answer :)

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob right now, but where? I don't see a button like it usually does.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour - The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".

Comment: @NextGDev: It will appear as a hollow checkmark below the vote control. When you click it, it will turn green, and your acceptance of that answer will be locked in. See [the site tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).